# Why doesn't Snowflake support CTE scope (any workaround?)

Tags: common-table-expression, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm a Business Intelligence (BI) consultant and I'm running into an issue where Snowflake doesn't support CTE scope.

In BI, it's incredibly useful to redefine bits of SQL. However, if I define a CTE called revenue_calculations then put something new in the where clause and re-declare revenue_calculations as a new CTE further down in the script(or nested within another CTE declaration), Snowflake only reads Revenue Calculations one time and uses the first CTE declaration throughout the script.

Most other databases (Bigquery for example) and programming languages have scope for objects. Is there any workaround to this? Will this be changing?

***Updated to include code sample

```
with cte_in_question as (select 1),
cte2 as (
    with cte_in_question as (select 2)
    select * from cte_in_question
)
SELECT * FROM cte2
```

Snowflake evaluates this to 1 and BQ to 2. 2 seems much more correct to me. Thoughts?

Comment: Can you add some sample code to your question?  The behavior you are describing sounds nomal for CTEs.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen done! :D

Comment: I don't understand your sample code or what it is supposed to be doing.  AFAIK Snowflake CTE follows the same standards as the other major RDBMS.

Comment: This is what Oracle EE 12c has to say about the query in question :D
32034. 00000 -  "unsupported use of WITH clause"
*Cause:    Inproper use of WITH clause because one of the following two reasons
           1. nesting of WITH clause within WITH clause not supported yet
           2. For a set query, WITH clause can't be specified for a branch.
           3. WITH clause cannot be specified within parenthesis.

Comment: When you say "most other databases" could you provide an example?  BigQuery isn't a database, it's a query engine, and the SQL that is accepted on it is a lot different in many cases from standard SQL.  I have not seen this example work in Oracle or SQL Server, and I'm not exactly sure what it is you're trying to accomplish with it.  You have 2 select statements in a single CTE definition.

Comment: @MikeWalton Amazon Redshift also will return the value 2. I haven't tested in Azure. But I'm speaking of MPP databases only.

I'm trying to be able to reuse SQL code with small modifications, without having to rewrite the SQL code in its entirety. This is a strictly BI use case.

Comment: @HansHenrikEriksen thank you! Hadn't tested in Oracle. This shows that different databases handle this differently, but from a programmers perspective having local scope is much more conforming to standard practice.

Comment: Snowflake is like Oracle, not supported _yet_.  It looks useful for maintenance reasons, you can cut&paste the SELECT part at multiple places and have it do different things based on the nearest CTE.  I believe you can vote for new functionality at the Snowflake Lodge, maybe give it a try.

Comment: @GregLi SQL uses scope both similarly and differently from other programming languages.  The key task is to build a result set, and that can be done from a global inner part and outwards and/or at the same time using helpers (CTEs and functions) following classical programming scope.    Anyhow, your suggestion has its uses and I can't see how it can break anything...

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that in Snowflake, by default, the data from outer CTE is returned. But this behaviour can be altered. You need to contact Snowflake support and request them to change this behaviour (at your account level) so that data from inner CTE will be returned.